# string not recognized as valid date time vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

i am getting "string not recognized as valid date" error while parsing date

```
Dim reviewDateString = "‎02‎/14‎/‎2019‎ ‎15‎:‎06‎:‎02"
DateTime.ParseExact(reviewDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

I have also tried with MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss format as well. That didnt work either.
Could anyone let me know wjat mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I pasted your exact code into dotnetfiddle.net, I can see non-visible characters (represented by a dot).  You need to clean your `reviewDateString` to remove those.

[image]

**Update**: Added an example of how to use regular expressions to parse non-visible chars (invalid date string chars)

Working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iQNhrp

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim reviewDateString = "‎02‎/14‎/‎2019‎ ‎15‎:‎06‎:‎02"
        Dim parsedDateString = RegEx.Replace(reviewDateString, "[^0-9a-zA-Z :/]", String.Empty)

        Console.WriteLine("Copy and paste this into dotnetfiddle to see it has invisible characters:")
        Console.WriteLine(reviewDateString)

        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Copy and paste this into dotnetfiddle to see it has no invisible characters, and is a valid date string.")
        Console.WriteLine(parsedDateString)

        ' no parse errors
        DateTime.ParseExact(parsedDateString, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Any ideas on how we can achieve  that in vb.net

Comment: You can use a regex to parse it out. I'll update the answer with a sample.

Comment: I have used a regex and it is working fine now. Thank you.